# Obj-c NSNotificationCenter Bad Access

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsnotificationcenter

So I have a CCLayer object which has a child CCSprite object, when a condition happens (detected by an update method) a method of the CCSprite is called which itself calls the following

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"mymethod" object:nil];
```

the CCLayer then goes on to run

```
[node removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
```

for the CCSprite to remove it. The CCLayer also called the following on init

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(mymethod) name:@"mymethod" object:nil];
```

Now 9 times out of 10 this is fine and works as expected however occasionally I get a bad_access pointing to the notification post line.

My guess from reading about other people having **similar** issues is that this is because the child object has been removed, but I don't know how else to do it as it is being called before it is removed.

Could something be happening to delay the post notification being called and it is ending up being called after the object is removed or am I barking up the wrong tree?

**UPDATE**

Added removal code above, if I comment out the remove and cleanup line it doesn't happen.

Comment: can you post the code where you remove the child?

Comment: you may want to post in the onExit method , if the parent class eventually is a cocos2d class.  onExit is invoked during the 'removeFromParent' cycle, and is executed prior to the actual removal. Dont forget to [super onExit].

Comment: Have U tried nor "removing" the object, just to see if it still happens?

Comment: Thanks for all your quick responses, see edits above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove the observer. Observers don't get removed automatically, so if you are not removing them then you stack them in memory, that could be the reason that it breaks later.

Comment: Excellent thanks, I've added the following to my dealloc method `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];` I'll give it a test.